# How can I open a PDF using SharePoint which opens outside of the browser? (I'm using Nitro not Adobe)

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf, promoted-links

I'm trying to use promoted links as a tile format which links to a PDF file (also saved on SharePoint. I've linked the promoted link with a URL which points to the PDF on SharePoint and asks it to open in a new tab. When I click on the tile it works fine, except the image quality is very poor quality.

Is there a way to open said PDF in to Nitro from the promoted link instead of the in browser option?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online has not supported opening PDF files directly in client application, neither when opening directly from document library nor using a promoted link.

If you are using IE, you can check as following:

1. Click Open > Open in browser when you open the PDF file in the new tab. Per my test, this will open the PDF in Adobe PDF Reader in web version which provide better quality of the PDF file.
2. If you disable Adobe PDF Reader via IE > Settings > Manage Add-ons and then click Open > Open in browser, the browser will promote if you want to open or save the PDF file from SharePoint Online. Select “Open” and IE will open the PDF file with client application.
   [image]

I cannot test with Nitro for you but you can give it a try.

Reference:

[SharePoint UserVoice: Open Adobe PDF in client application](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/12336546-open-adobe-pdf-in-client-application)